# defining a tuple data type of unknown length in Rascal

Tags: rascal

I was curious to know if one could define a data type that we know, should be a tuple, but whose length (or number of elements is indeterminable) currently. The application is as follows:

```
//I want to declare a data type, one of whose argument is a tuple,
public data MyType=fromListCartesianProduct(tuple<?> product)


//Later I want to instantiate a MyType data by using taking List-CartesianProduct

//instantiate some MyType data
foreach(aTuple in [1,2,3]*["a","b"])
    someArr[i]=fromListCartesianProduct(aTuple)
```

The salient observation is that the number of elements in aTuple is indeterminable while declaring "MyType". Can I still declare such a type in a rascal script?

As an alternate, I would declare MyType as:

```
public data MyType=fromListCartesianProduct(list[] product)
```

and convert each tuple from taking the cartesian product into a list before constructing the specific instances. For reasons of clarity and others, I would like to define MyType as I previously did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principe the answer is no. Tuples have fixed length and we do not (yet) have row polymorphism.

Having said that, data constructors do support different kinds of polymorphism which might help:

- row polymorphism using keyword parameters, you can always add more keyword parameters to a data-type, as in

  ```
  data MyType = myCons(int j = 0); // initial decl
  data MyType(int k = 1); // extension with another field
  ```
- overloading, you can always add more constructors with more parameters

  ```
  data MyType = f(int i); // initial declaration
  data MyType = f(int i, int j); // overloaded declaration with more fields
  ```

You might use the `make` function from `Type` to dynamically construct such constructors based on argument lists. At the risk of run-time type exceptions of course.

Another way of dealing with data of unpredictable type is to go up one level in the type hierarchy (let it be `value`), and later pattern match your way out again:

```
   list[value] myListRelationOfUnknownType = ...;
   for (<int i, int j> <- myListRelationOfUnknownType)
      println("printing only pairs of ints: <i> - <j>");
   for (<int i, int j, int k> <- myListRelationOfUnknownType)
      println("printing only the triples of ints: <i> - <j> - <k>");
```

That's a statically more safe way.